# Ruby on rails password field and text field alignment

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ruby on rails platform. I am designing a form with text fields. In the beginning, I created a simple html file with css to align the text fields. Below is my css

```
#input{

padding-left:50px;
padding-bottom:30px;

}
```

I created text fields using following code:

```
<div id = "input"><input type = "text" size = "25" name = "fname" value = "first name"></input></div>
<div id = "input"><input type = "text" size = "25" name = "lname" value = "last name"></input></div>
```

When I ran the web page, I saw the text field aligned properly the way I wanted inside form. However I tried to convert the code in RoR, I am not able to see padding. Below is my code in RoR

```
<div class="input"><%= f.text_field :fname, :size => 25, :placeholder => 'first name' %></div>
<div class="input"><%= f.text_field :lname, :size => 25, :placeholder => 'last name' %></div>
```

Can anyone tell me what might be the issue with my approach?

Comment: How are you loading your stylesheet in your rails application? Are you sure you've included it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the css code `#input{..}` the hash `#` means that it is looking for an **id**. After you have changed the code, you set it to `class="input"`. Therefore the css can't find it by **id**. Change the css to `.input{..}`.

Comment: It aligned it a bit but not like it aligns in simple html code.

Comment: when you render the page, try to use firebug/inspect element and see whether another css rule conflicts with this rule. Maybe the `padding-left: 30px;` is not enough.